# A* algorithm when the heuristic can not be calculated for some nodes

Tags: graph, artificial-intelligence, shortest-path, path-finding, a-star

I am working on a dataset of cities and towns spread across North America with the objective of finding the shortest path between a starting point and an ending point. I decided to use the Haversine distance as my heuristic function. But, my dataset doesn't have the latitude and longitude coordinates for some of the towns that could lie in the shortest distance path. How am I supposed to calculate the heuristic in this case? Would taking the average of the heuristics of the neighboring towns make sense?

It is given that a town/city without its corresponding coordinates cant be the starting point or the ending point.

Is there a different heuristic I should be considering instead of the Haversive distance?

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO! I would recommend reading through [SO tour
page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and through SO help center on [how to
ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Use google maps to find the lat/lon of the towns that are missing that data.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly (don’t trust me on this!) a heuristic that returns zero for some nodes is still ["legal"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_heuristic) (in the sense that when you get to the end node, you know it’s optimal), so that would be a brutal solution. Obviously, doing this for too many nodes would wreck your search performance!

I think that interpolating between neighbour locations risks creating an inadmissible heuristic.